# Need help understanding View Controller life Cycle

Tags: ios, swift, breakpoints

When I run an app in Xocde ios 9 with swift I get an error that says "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". Now I am trying to look which value is the nil being caused by. I am using break points to help me do so. I placed a break point on viewDidLoad and no error. Then I placed a break point on viewWillAppear and got the error again. Now I do not know where to place the break point. Can someone explain to me where I should place the break points based on the view controller life cycle.

Comment: What is the exception stack trace?

Comment: Sorry don't understand what you mean by stack trace?

Comment: posting your code would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Life Cycle is

```
func viewDidLoad()

func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)

func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simulator and it gonna show the exact string )